# Python - Split the image in the center of the image

Tags: python, opencv, extract

Currently, I have an array containing the coordinates of the midpoints then I use it to draw a line through those coordinates.  Then I want to split the image above and below the body line that I drew, but I have no idea for it, so please give me an idea; I really appreciate it

I want the result to look like this picture
[image: image description]

array a = [(954, 88), (905, 97), (855, 107), (805, 114), (755, 125), (705, 134), (655, 139), (605, 141), (555, 139), (505, 134), (455,
139), (405, 146), (355, 146), (305, 144), (255, 145), (205, 1
25), (155, 120), (105, 114), (55, 104), (1, 156)]

image used to run the program :
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7njNs.png)
and the results after running :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54cYx.png)

Comment: Post your original image and your coordinate list

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have corrected the question and attached the picture

Comment: `@Mirote` That linked image does not correspond to your posted picture. It looks like a thresholded version. Is that really your original image? Also is your array in the order x,y or y,x?

Comment: Because the image I took from an article, it's blurry sorry, and those coordinates are in x,y terms. I was originally going to use a binary image of the salmon but you asked for the original so I edited it as described. The threshold I used for this image is 178

Comment: It would be better to have your actual salmon input image than your binarized image.  Don't you want to see the actual fish split in halves?  Why are you asking this question if you do not have real data rather than something scanned from some article?

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried?  What research have you done to try to solve it?  Please read the information guides in the help center (stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question"

Comment: What I would do would be to take your list of points and draw them as a polygon going from the side of the image to your end points and then closing the polygon with the 2 corners for each side. I would draw that polygon as white filled on a black background and use that as a mask (see cv2.fillPoly()). One mask for each side. Then I would use each mask to black out the image for the the non-white areas using Numpy processing.

Comment: thank you very much what you provide is really helpful for me , it helps me to solve the problem successfully

Comment: `@Mirote` If my answer was useful, it is customary to give it an up-vote. Please see the help file of this forum about voting

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- List Numpy array of original points
- Draw polygon on input copy from array of points
- Augment the array of points to make a polygon around the top of the image
- Draw a white filled polygon on a black background as mask1
- Use the mask1 to blacken out the bottom and keep the top of the input image
- Augment the array of points to make a polygon around the bottom of the image
- Draw a white filled polygon on a black background as mask2
- Use the mask2 to blacken out the top and keep the bottom of the input image
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('fish.png')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# create black image like input
black = np.zeros_like(img)

# define original point
points = np.array([[954,88],[905,97],[855,107],[805,114],[755,125],[705,134],[655,139],[605,141],[555,139],[505,134],[455,139],[405,146],[355,146],[305,144],[255,145],[205,125],[155,120],[105,114],[55,104],[1,156]])

# draw points on input
img_pts = img.copy()
cv2.polylines(img_pts, [points], False, (0,0,255), 2)


# augment original polygon array for top region
points1 = np.array([[0,0],[w-1,0],[w-1,88],[954,88],[905,97],[855,107],[805,114],[755,125],[705,134],[655,139],[605,141],[555,139],[505,134],[455,139],[405,146],[355,146],[305,144],[255,145],[205,125],[155,120],[105,114],[55,104],[1,156],[0,156]])

# draw white filled closed polygon on black background
mask1 = black.copy()
cv2.fillPoly(mask1, [points1], (255,255,255))

# Use mask to select top part of image
result1 = np.where(mask1==255, img, black)

# augment polygon array for bottom region
points2 = np.array([[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,88],[954,88],[905,97],[855,107],[805,114],[755,125],[705,134],[655,139],[605,141],[555,139],[505,134],[455,139],[405,146],[355,146],[305,144],[255,145],[205,125],[155,120],[105,114],[55,104],[1,156],[0,156]])

# draw white filled closed polygon on black background
mask2 = black.copy()
cv2.fillPoly(mask2, [points2], (255,255,255))

# Use mask to select part of image
result2 = np.where(mask2==255, img, black)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('fish_with_points.jpg', img_pts)
cv2.imwrite('fish_top_mask.jpg', mask1)
cv2.imwrite('fish_top_masked.jpg', result1)
cv2.imwrite('fish_bottom_mask.jpg', mask2)
cv2.imwrite('fish_bottom_masked.jpg', result2)

# show results
cv2.imshow('img_points',img_pts)
cv2.imshow('mask1',mask1)
cv2.imshow('result1',result1)
cv2.imshow('mask2',mask2)
cv2.imshow('result2',result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Original Point Polyline on Input:

[image]

Mask1:

[image]

Result1:

[image]

Mask2:

[image]

Result2:

[image]